# Proving that two points on elliptic curve are within range

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is it possible to prove that a point on an elliptic curve falls within a given range of another point, without revealing the distance between them. For example:

Let's say $X$ and $Y$ are two points on an elliptic curve such that $X = x \cdot G$ and $Y = y \cdot G$, where $G$ is the generator. The proover knows values of $x$ and $y$, and wants to prove to the verifier that $|x - y| < z$, where $z$ is some value supplied by the verifier.

**Another option**: prove that $\frac{x}{y} < z$, where $z$ can be a relatively small number (e.g. 2).

Is either of these possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof showing that,  given $G$ and $x \cdot G$ and a range $[A,B]$, $x$ is in the range $[A,B]$ is known as **the range proof**.
In your case, we can convert your statement as the range proof as, given $G$ and $H = xG - yG$, showing $x-y$ is in the range $[-z,z]$.

For example, the following papers (and a lot of papers) proposed efficient range proofs.

- [Jan Camenisch, Rafik Chaabouni, and abhi shelat: Efficient Protocols for Set Membership and Range Proofs (ASIACRYPT 2008)](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/128718/files/CCS08.pdf)
- [Benedikt Bünz and Jonathan Bootle and Dan Boneh and Andrew Poelstra and Pieter Wuille and Greg Maxwell: Bulletproofs: Short Proofs for Confidential Transactions and More (IEEE S&P 2018)](https://crypto.stanford.edu/bulletproofs/)