# How does one go about implementing a range proof?

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs

I've attempted to find a solution to this problem, but for the life of me I am unable to. I am attempting to solve whether a point an elliptic curve of prime order is between 2 points, given a specific generator point, similar to the question posted here: [Proving that two points on elliptic curve are within range](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66058/proving-that-two-points-on-elliptic-curve-are-within-range?rq=1&newreg=f52a312679a1456da791af823a1bc32f)

I would like to include it in my existing ECC python script. However, I've never actually seen anyone implement it with code, or even explain the process step-by-step. There are a bunch of papers and sites explaining how great and efficient it is, yet I am unable to find a resource to help me code it. Does anyone have a resource that would be able to help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Could you provide python script? Maybe I can help you.